# Determining critical points of multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, systems-of-equations, self-learning

Let $ g\left(x,y\right) = x^3 -9xy^2 +9y^4 + 23$

and the gradient of that function:

$$ \nabla g\left(x,y\right) = \left( 3x^2 -9y^2 \space , \space -18xy + 36y^3 \right)^T$$

To solve for $$ \nabla g\left(x,y\right) = \left(0,0\right)$$
 I did the following steps:

$$ 3x^2 - 9y^2  = 0 \\ -18xy + 36y^3 = 0$$

---

$$ x^2 - 3y^2 = 0 \\ -xy + 2y^3 = 0$$

---

$$ x^2 = 3y^2 \rightarrow (x = 0) \land (y = 0)$$ Since anything squared is positive and setting those values to zero is the only way to satisfy this equation

$$ 2y^3 = xy $$  This is where I'm kind of stuck. If $ x= 0 $ then $ y =0 $.
**But when I try to verify my answer with a online tool I see that I missed a critical point.**

The critical point which  I found at $(0,0)^T$ seems to be a saddle point since the Hesse Matrix $H g(x,y)$ is indefinite at that point.

What mistake did I make ?

Comment: We have the equations $2y^2=x$ ($2y^3=xy$ divided by $y$, if $y\ne 0$) and $3y^2=x^2$ . Dividing those equations gives $x=\frac{3}{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y \ne 0$, then we get from $2y^3=xy$ that $x=2y^2$. From $x^2=3y^2$ we then derive

$4y^4=3y^2$.

Therefore $4y^2=3$.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: $$ 4y^2 = 3  \\ y^2 = \frac{3}{4} \\ y = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} $$ from peters comment we also know $x= \frac{3}{2}$ when $y \neq 0 $ so the next critical point is $(\frac{3}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$, correct ?

Comment: From $ y^2 = \frac{3}{4}$ we get $y =  \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ !

Comment: oops, my mistake, thanks for noticing